# "stack smashing detected" by getline & printf - and i really cant figure out why

Tags: c, gcc, overflow

when it comes to C i am not a noob - i'm more like a total & complete stupid ignorant noob! i am trying to write a program to parse simple text files, and i would like to make it as general as possible(why i use getline). well here is my code:

```
//afile.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main( )
{FILE *fp1;
char *filename;
char **line;
size_t *sz;
int s;

filename = "n";
if ((fp1 = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL ){printf("error...");return 1;}
        do {
    s = getline(&line,sz,fp1);
if (s != -1)
  printf(" %s  \n",line);//<-- %s seems to be wrong! %*s removes the gcc warning  
} while (s != EOF); 
fclose(fp1);}
```

I am pretty sure its some pointer allocation problem, but i really cant figure out where it is. i've found out that replacing %s with %*s makes the compiler warning disappear, but it results in an infinity of \t(tabs) being written in the terminal.
By the way, the error message i get is:* 
     stack smashing detected *: ./afile terminated
    Segmentation fault

Comment: Try initializing `line = NULL`

Comment: char **line doesn't seem right to me

Answer (score 2):

You failed to initialize the line variable, and it contains a random value. Readline probably tries to realloc() it.
UPDATE: the definition for line is also wrong, only one asterix needed, as pointed out by others.

```
int main(void )
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char *filename;
    char *line = NULL; /* <- here */
    size_t *sz;
    int s;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getline` expects an argument of type `char**`, and you supplied `&line`, which is `char***`. Additionally, `getline` acts on the *current* value of the value its first arguments points to (so, the value of `line`), and you didn't initialize it. Change your program to:

```
char *line = NULL;
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer redirections are inconsistent. The variable line is declared:

```
char **line;
```

Which is a pointer to a pointer to a character, or a pointer to a string. getline() expects a pointer to a string, but you pass &line - a pointer to a pointer to a string.

Finally, your printf() format specified is %s, do it wants to format a string, but you give it a pointer to a string.

Long story short: remove an asterisk to create

```
char *line;
```